# Как исправить некорректную работу анимации кнопки?

Tags: android, java

Здраствуйте! Возникла проблема. В разметке присутствует две кнопки. Слушатель и анимация для обеих кнопок одни и те же. При первом нажатии все происходит правильно, но при следующем нажатии на другую кнопку анимации происходит у обеих. Как это исправить? Вот сокращенная версия кода.

```
private OnClickListener mButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.startAnimation(buttonAnimation);

        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.first_button:
            //...
        case R.id.second_button:
            //...
    }
}
```

Кнопки свою функцию выполняют правильно

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю была ли проблема в этом, но решилась тем, что стал использовать разные переменные Animation (в данном случае использовалась одна - buttonAnimation) для разных элементов управления(кнопок).
Если кто знает причины этой проблемы - рад буду услышать.